# jQuery not loading on first page visit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue loading the jQuery library when I visit my webpage for the first time. Therefore, none of its functions work. If I visit another page on my site, or reload it, the script works and continues to from there on and to recreate the issue, I have to clear my cookies. I have checked my code and it seems fine to me, I think its something to do with the PHP configuration of the server but I am not too sure.

I have posted this question before but Now i have narrowed down my problem and here is a video [link](http://intellectuni.com/fmyscript.html) of the issue in action.

Comment: Firebug and its "network" tab shows you what gets loaded and when. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Relevant HTML source for the page in question might be useful in assisting with this issue.

Comment: This question follows the other one Tim has asked and not marked as answered/resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619968/javascript-does-not-load-in-initial-page-load

Comment: The video doesn't work at all for me (Firefox/Linux).

You need to post the code or absolutely nobody that isn't psychic will be able to help.

Comment: you should be able to see the code > view page source, Im just using the JQuery library functions

Answer (score 0):

Try to have jQuery wait for document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function submitToggle() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Is this the problem?

Comment: that can be abbreviated "$(function() { ... })" -- but we don't know what the code looks like so it's impossible to tell whether that's the problem.

Comment: @Pointy, actually you can look at the code... just surf to http://intellectuni.com/ and check it from there. This was the first warning that popped my eyes. Maybe there are other red flags.

Comment: yes thats the problem the submit button is not being called, if i go to the "top" page and then everything starts to work

Answer (score 0):

actually this is silly but guys I have resolved my problem I had to use http://"www" rather then http://

so the domain wasn't configured for "http://".

Comment: Great, perhaps you should flag your answer as the correct one? :)